# Erratic code execution from a Windows Service

Tags: c#, windows, windows-services

My first post to StackOverflow.

I have traditionally developed Windows Forms applications in C# in various versions of Visual Studio (largely 2010) but have been tasked with developing a Windows Service (using VS 2013).  Written in C#, I am repurposing an existing service written by a developer no longer with our organization.

I would provide code samples but the issue is not with any single method.  The problem I am experiencing is radically strange code execution patterns when debugging the service. The code may jump to locations you would not expect and it often repeats execution of code it should have already moved past.  I've never seen anything like this.  It is almost as though there are multiple instances running but I have not been able to confirm more than a single instance running.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how this might be occurring?

When Stepping Over, the code might jump from line 54 to 56 then back to 54 repeatedly.  Even if it dropped BACK into this method, the code should never reach line 54 with having stopped first at 38 or 43.

Thank you very much for your input,
Michael

[Code Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GUoQJ.jpg)

Comment: For starters, move the code from screenshot into your issue. Easier to view/help with actual code vs screenshot.

Comment: Sounds like there may be multiple threads executing in parallel so in your debugger, you're seeing breakpoints being hit in a seemingly random order.  But it's not, you are just seeing the fact that different threads are executing at a different location in your code whenever the thread context switches.

Comment: Sounds to me like you're debugging a release-mode executable.  Due to compiler optimizations, the code doesn't necessarily run in the order you might expect.

Comment: Thank you all for the feedback.  I initially attempted to place the screenshot with the issue but the form indicated that I could not do so, ergo the link.  After thinking about this over the weekend, I came back in this morning with a fresh perspective and dug into a different area of the code.  In essence I left a line commented out from an earlier troubleshooting attempt.  While the service was running in a single instance, the commented line was allowing multiple loops of the primary routine that drives all other code execution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within the Windows service is:

```
private System.Timers.Timer _timer;

protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    _timer = new System.Timers.Timer { Interval = 1000 };
    _timer.Elapsed += TimerElapsed;
    _timer.Enabled = true;
}

/// <summary>
/// Event raised every second
/// IsBusy flag ensures no overlapping processing
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sender"></param>
/// <param name="e"></param>
private void TimerElapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsRunning) return;
        if (IsBusy) return; //Line was commented out
        IsBusy = true;
        ProcessRequestLogRecords();
        IsBusy = false;
    }
```

Due to an unhandled error occurring elsewhere, IsBusy was never being reset to False and therefore ProcessRequestLogRecords (which drives ALL the service's functionality) would be bypassed during the next cycle.  I had commented out the line indicated above while tracking down the unhandled exception but failed to uncomment it once the error was corrected (probably a day or more later).  This was allowing ProcessRequestLogRecords to be called independently of the cycle I was monitoring while debugging with breakpoints.

Lesson learned.  Thank you again to those who contributed!  I certainly appreciate your efforts!

Michael